# how to run java app on ec2 server 24/7?

Tags: java, android, amazon-ec2, putty

I have a Java application that acts as a server side for my android app, and it's located in my instance of Amazon ec2. I can run that java app through putty, which means that my computer has to stay on. How can I change that so the instance will constantly run that Java application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run application as a service or run application in background.

Service or running in background depends on which operating system your using.

Comment: Great man thanks! I run it on a linux instance so I append & to the end of the command.

Comment: How can I stop the app from running?

Comment: you can stop by killing the process, that is not the better way. Best way is to run in it as service and start and stop. If you dont want to go by service for now, you can kill the process. "ps -ef | grep "process_name" " , and find the process id , and " kill process_id"